# Rails 5.1 capistrano is stuck at webpacker compiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relay, webpacker

I'm trying to deploy a rails 5.1 app with capistrano and it seems to be stuck at compiling assets:

```
02:38 deploy:assets:precompile
  01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
  01 yarn install v0.27.5
  01 [1/4] Resolving packages...
  01 [2/4] Fetching packages...
  01 warning fsevents@1.1.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
  01 info "fsevents@1.1.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
  01 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
  01 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
  01 Done in 48.92s.
  01 Webpacker is installed  
  01 Using /project_name/releases/20170807195158/config/webpack/paths.yml file for setting up webpack paths
  01 Compiling webpacker assets
```

There are no errors, it just stays there for hours. If i inspect the node process doing this on the remote server it says that it uses 100% of the cpu for about 5 minutes and then the process seems to get killed but it still says "Compiling assets".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that executing bundle exec rake assets:precompile on remote when there are more than a few assets fails.

The solution was to compile the assets locally and then rsync them to the remote server.